# A question about operator representation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $A$ be a compact operator acting on $H$. 
In general we may write $H = E_A\oplus E_A^\perp$. Let us consider the $2\times 2$ operator
matrix of $A$ relative to the decomposition $H = E_A\oplus E_A^\perp$. Since $E_A$ is invariant
under $A$, the element in the left lower corner is the zero operator. Thus
 \begin{eqnarray*} A= \begin{bmatrix}A_{11} &  A_{12}  \\ 0  &  A_{22} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Here $E_A$ means the
smallest closed linear manifold of $H$ containing all eigenvectors and generalized
eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to non-zero eigenvalues.

I don't understand why the element in the left lower corner is the zero operator?

Comment: The left lower corner is 0 iff $E_A$ is invariant under $A$. From your definition of $E_A$, can you see why it is invariant?

Comment: Can you explain it in term of linear algebra? I am teaching myself functional analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower left corner is the operator $(I-P)AP$, where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $E_A$. For any $x\in H$, $P(x)\in E_A$, thus $A(P(x))\in E_A$, therefore $P(A(P(x)))=A(P(x))$. Hence $A(P(x))-P(A(P(x)))=0$, thus $(I-P)AP(x)=0$.